# Por que no se ven las animaciones de css en el navegador?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo una pagina web y le agregue anmaciones al titulo, pero no se si es el navegador o el editor(uso vscode)
tampoco me muestra unos letter-spacing que agregue.
Que podria ser?

Comment: Para ayudarte es necesario saber el codigo, te recomiendo leer [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Tal vez es porque estas importando mal (si es un archivo a parte)

Comment: ya añadí la imagen como respuesta a mi comentario, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mí que tenes cacheadas en el navegador tus hojas de estilo, proba ingresando al sitio nuevamente y presiona **ctrl + shift + r** (esto funciona para chrome) para recargar toda la página de forma forzosa.

Esto haría que al ingresar a la página obtengas la última versión de tus css, js, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, no me funciono eso.

Comment: Ya logre solucionar el problema

Comment: Genial, tenías alguna url apuntando mal a tus hojas? que era?

Comment: @SantiagoBetancourt si no te funciono, porque lo marcas como respuesta?

Comment: @SantiagoBetancourt porque aceptaste una respuesta que no soluciona el problema? como es que solucionaste el problema? donde esta el codigo en tu pregunta?

Answer (score -1):

Primero que todo intenta ponerlo todo en tu pregunta, la imagen la podrías haber puesto al editar la pregunta,

Respecto tu código, necesito que muestres más, en .heading-primary-main estás declarando que vas a usar la animación llamada "moveInLeft", pero yo no veo en ningún sitio que crees esa animación.

Aquí tienes un enlace dónde se ve como se define esa animación y posteriormente se crea.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#haciendo_que_un_texto_se_delice_por_la_ventana_del_navegador

Si te ha servido la respuesta, dale al check que aparece en la izquierda! Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, intente añadir el código pero no me dejaban publicar la pregunta, así que preferí no poner el código.

Comment: Puedes subir todo el código? Edita tu pregunta así veo por que te falla, adjunta el css completo, te falta declarar la animacion

```
@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```